# Why Shiny is looking for my static image in folder "_w_foo", rahter than www where it is?

Tags: r, shiny

I have this code that is working fine when running directly in RStudio. However when I upload it to https://miequiz.shinyapps.io/Bubbles/ it cannot find the static image *IE2004mxBis(EN).png*.

Inspecting the displayed page I found that it is looking for it at **https://miequiz.shinyapps.io/Bubbles/_w_36123d32/IE2004mxBis(EN).png** instead of **www** where I have it, as indicated in Shiny documentation. Obviously failing to find it. What am I doing wrong? is it a bug?

```
# This is a Shiny web application.
#
# Displayis a motionchart of EI and a map of IE in Mexico
#
#
library("shiny")
library("googleVis")
long_todo <- read.csv(file = "zvh_estados_long.csv",
                      stringsAsFactors = F)
titulos <- names(long_todo)
titulos <- sub("zvh", "Holdridge_LifeZone", titulos)
titulos <- sub("biomasa", "Biomass", titulos)
titulos <- sub("anom", "IE_Anomaly_(IE_mean2004)", titulos)
titulos <- sub("Entidad", "State", titulos)
titulos <- sub("area", "Area", titulos)
names(long_todo) <- titulos
long_todo$Holdridge_LifeZone <- iconv(long_todo$Holdridge_LifeZone,
                                      from = "latin1", to="UTF-8")
long_todo$State <- iconv(long_todo$State, from = "latin1", to="UTF-8")

# Deines details of the user interface
ui <- shinyUI(fluidPage(theme = "bootstrap.css",
  fluidRow(
    column(10, offset = 2,
           headerPanel ("Ecosystem Integrity")) # Título de la aplicación
          ),

  fluidRow(
    column(5, offset = 1,
           # Combo para elegir Entidad
           sidebarLayout(position = "left",
                         selectInput("entidad", "Choose a State: ",
                                     sort(unique(long_todo$State))),

           # Muestra la gráfica de distribución de integridad
           mainPanel(htmlOutput("ieGrafAnimada"))
           )),

    column(4, offset = 1,
              img(src="IE2004mxBis(EN).png", height=300, width=370),
                  style="text-align: right;",
                  style="vertical-align: bottom;")
  )
))

# Define server logic required to draw a MotionChart
server <- shinyServer(function(input, output) {

  output$ieGrafAnimada <- renderGvis({
    # Gráfica dinámica de burbujas
    Motion=gvisMotionChart(subset(long_todo, State==input$entidad),
                           idvar="id", timevar="year",
                           xvar = "IE",
                           yvar = "IE_Anomaly-vs2004",
                           colorvar = "Holdridge_LifeZone",
                           sizevar = "Area",
                           options = list(chartid= "Burbujas",
                                          width=647, height=400,
                                          tooltip="{isHtml:'True'}"))

    return(Motion)
  })

  outputOptions(output, "ieGrafAnimada", suspendWhenHidden = FALSE)
})

# Run the application
shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your problem lies in your image file name, get rid of the parenthesis and everything will work. It is probably related to the way shiny handles files, so you might consider it a bug.